# How to highlight the active row with only VBA

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have a code that adds two Conditional Formatting Rules to Sheet 4 (Column A2:A & Last row), and now I am trying to highlight the active row until the last column (For example, Column B:E of the active row). Currently I have this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then

    Dim lr As Long

    lr = Range("A" & Sheet4.rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With Range("A2:A" & lr)

            .FormatConditions.Delete

            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=COUNTIF('Test 2'!$A:$A,A2)>0"

            .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)

            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=COUNTIF('Test 2'!$A:$A,A2)=0"

            .FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206)

        End With 

    End If

End Sub
```

***I have two possible solutions***

**(1) Add Conditional Formatting to the Active Row AFTER Column A (So For example B:E of the active Row. I am using this code after the `End If` in the code above.**

```
If Application.CutCopyMode = False Then
Application.Calculate
End If

With Target

.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=CELL("row")=ROW()"
.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(220, 239, 206)

End With
```

I seem to be getting an error with the Formula for the conditional format, `.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=CELL("row")=ROW()"`

(2)
I have added a line to define the Name of Column A in the Active Row to "MyRange" for another purpose, so I also tried adding this code now instead of condition formatting:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="MyRange", RefersToR1C1:=Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select                                                   'Always Selects Column A depending on the Active Row selected
    Range("B:E" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Interior.Color = RGB(243, 243, 123)

End Sub
```

There error for the second solution is with `Range("B:E" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Interior.Color = RGB(243, 243, 123)`

The output of the code should look like this[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would go the `Selection Change` route here, but there may be a simpler way to do it than what you are currently attempting.

Comment: Yes I agree, `Selection Change` seems like a better route, and seeing as I already am using it up to the `Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select ` for another purpose, I would like to just add it here somehow. Do you know why it possibly isn't working?

Comment: `"B:E" & (ActiveCell.Row)` doesn't give you a valid range reference. You need to repeat the row number for each column, so the output is something like `B5:E5`.

Comment: I agree, I found a solution that works, see below

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general approach to this type of task:

1. Create  a workbook Name "THE_ROW" and give it an initial value of 0
2. Add a formula-based conditional format to the range of interest:

[image]
3. For the selection_change event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ThisWorkbook.Names("THE_ROW").RefersTo = "=" & Target(1).Row
End Sub
```

Not *quite* as specified, since it only highlights populated cells...

Using CF over setting the fill means you don't need to worry about overwriting existing fills when you highlight the row.

Answer (score 0):

Solved solution 2, highlights the active row:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="MyRange", RefersToR1C1:=Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select                                                   'Always Selects Column A depending on the Active Row selected

    Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

    With Target

        'Highlights the entire row that contain the active cell
        .EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(243, 243, 123)

    End With

End Sub
```

To ONLY Highlight the active Row:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

    With Target

        'Highlights the entire row that contain the active cell
        .EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(243, 243, 123)

    End With

End Sub
```